# Как выровнять блоки?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выровнять кнопки, чтобы было как на 2 картинке?

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 2rem;
   color: #fff;
   background: #222 url("../Images/bg.png") center no-repeat;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.btn {
 margin-left: 1.33rem;
 
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #fff;
 background: transparent;
 font-size: 1.06rem;
 
 padding: 1rem 4rem;
 
 border: 1px solid #F80759;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
   max-width: 1200px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 15px;
}

/* Price */

.price__item:hover {
 border: 1px solid #12C2E9;
}

.price__item:hover .price__count {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #E100FF, #F80759);
}

.price__item:hover .btn--price {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #E100FF, #F80759);
}

.price__inner {
 text-align: center;
}

.price__title {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 font-weight: 600;
 color: #12C2E9;
 
 margin-bottom: 0.73rem;
}

.price__suptitle {
 font-size: 2rem;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.price__suptitle:after {
 content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 0.3rem;
    margin: 3.33rem auto;

    background: linear-gradient(to right, #E100FF, #F80759);
}

.price__price {
 display: flex;
 
 justify-content: center;
}

.price__item {
 margin: 2rem;
 border: 2px solid #222;
}

.price__money {
 margin: 1.5rem 6.66rem;
 font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.price__span {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 3.2rem;
}

.price__count {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 background-color: #222;
 padding: 15px 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.price__text {
 font-size: 0.93rem;
 margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
}

.price__more {
 color: #F80759;
}

.btn--price {
 margin: 2rem;
 border: 1px solid #222;
}

.btn--price:hover {
 background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="price__inner">
   <h2 class="price__title">ВЫБИРАЙТЕ</h2>
   <h1 class="price__suptitle">НАШИ УСЛУГИ</h1>
   <div class="price__price">
   
    <div class="price__item">
     <div class="price__money">от<span class="price__span">1000</span>₽</div>
      <div class="price__count">Создание игр</div>
      <div class="price__text">
       <p>Создание 2D игр на движке</p>
       <p>Unity и языке</p>
       <p>программирования  JavaScript</p>
       <p>под любые платформы и</p>
       <p>даже браузер</p>
      </div>
      
      <button class="btn btn--price">Заказать игру</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="price__item">
     <div class="price__money">от<span class="price__span">500</span>₽</div>
      <div class="price__count">Разработка и доработка сайтов</div>
      <div class="price__text">
       <p>Сайты услуг</p>
       <p>Лендинги</p>
       <p>Визитки</p>
       <p>Информационные сайты</p>
       <p>Тематические сайты</p>
       <p>Блоги</p>
       <div class="price__more">И многое другое</div>
      </div>
      
      <button class="btn btn--price">Заказать сайт</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="price__item">
     <div class="price__money">от<span class="price__span">100</span>₽</div>
      <div class="price__count">Дизайн</div>
      <div class="price__text">
       <p>Логотипы</p>
       <p>Дизайн сайта</p>
       <p>Работа с фото</p>
       <p>Персонажи игр</p>
       <p>Дизайн интерфейса игр</p>
       <div class="price__more">И многое другое</div>
      </div>
      
      <button class="btn btn--price">Заказать дизайн</button>
    </div>
    
   </div> <!-- ./price__price -->
  </div> <!-- ./price__inner -->
 </div> <!-- ./container -->
</div> <!-- ./price -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.price__item {
  ..
  ..
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Ну и можно border заменить на outline при наведении, что бы они так не скакали.

Comment: Или изначально задать прозрачный border 1px